# Is there a clean way in Rust to mutate a `&mut` by replacing its value?

Tags: rust, lifetime, language-features, ownership, mutable-reference

Is there a clean way to implement a **safe** function `g` that mutates a mutable reference by applying `f` on its value without having to implement `Clone` or `Default` (or any other special trait) for `T`? If not, why is or should this not be possible?

Imagine a type `T` and a function `f`:

```rust
fn f(v: T) -> T;
```

For example:

```rust
fn f(mut v: u32) -> u32 {
    v += 1;
    v
}
```

The following code is invalid because `p` cannot be dereferenced:

```rust
fn g(p: &mut T) {
    *p = f(*p)
}
```

I searched and tried many things, but I didn't come up with a safe solution.

---

For people who are interested for the cases where `Clone` and `Default` are allowed:

- By implementing `Clone` you could do:

  ```rust
  fn g(p: &mut T) {
      *p = f(p.clone())
  }
  ```
- By implementing `Default` you could do:

  ```rust
  fn g(p: &mut T) {
      let val = core::mem::take(p);
      core::mem::replace(p, f(val));
  }
  ```

Comment: TL;DR: No, there is not.

Comment: Could you try to describe the flow or scenario in which you'd want to do this instead of this hypothetical?

Comment: @Stargateur Could you please clarify which part of the question you consider unclean
@MasterBait I've got a Window-Trait, that has a function `draw` that should return a type that implements my Draw-Trait and is living maximum as long as the window. The Window-Trait should specify which Draw-Type to use. But now it is not possible to deliver that Window::Draw a lifetime. However it is possible to consume Window and return a Draw-Object that is back-convertible into the Window. This function would be analog to `f` in my question. But I'd also like to have a function in `g`-style.

Comment: @Natrix could be better but you fix it in your last edit

Comment: this message is for ping @MasterBait because natrix try to ping you but comment can only ping one person